# C# Mongo driver ReplaceOneModel inserting null _id on upsert

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, upsert

I'm trying to bulk upsert a collection in .net core 2 using the c# mongo driver.  The problem I'm having is that the _id field is always inserted as null.

Here's the code:

```
  public async Task UpsertEvents(IEnumerable<Event> events)
    {
        if(events.Count()>0){
            List<ReplaceOneModel<Event>> requests = new List<ReplaceOneModel<Event>>();
            foreach (var ev in events)
                {
                var filter = new FilterDefinitionBuilder<Event>().Where(m => m.Id == ev.Id);
                var request = new ReplaceOneModel<Event>(filter,ev);
                request.IsUpsert = true;
                requests.Add(request);
                }
            await _context.Events.BulkWriteAsync(requests);
        }
    }
```

And the object:

```
 public class Event
    {
        [BsonIgnoreIfDefault]
        [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
        public string Id { get; set; }
    }
```

There are more fields, but they're not really relevant here.

Any ideas why its inserting null for the id?  A normal insert produces the ID correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Use UpdateOneModel and list all the properties in the update.

```
List<UpdateOneModel<Event>> requests = new List<UpdateOneModel<Event>>();
var update = Builders<Event>.Update.Set("field", "value");
var request = new UpdateOneModel<Event>(filter,update);
```

Read the explanation [`here`](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/mongodb-user/upsert$20replace$20c$23%7Csort:date/mongodb-user/M1lNFLLWu7k/N04bQepdsRIJ) why upsert with replacement inserts a null value in id.  However,         [BsonIgnoreIfDefault] should work for you.

Comment: Thank you.  I'll very likely do that, and it does work, it's just a little more to maintain, and I don't understand why BsonIgnoreIfDefault isn't working.

Comment: Please consider accepting the answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and i Fix it using this :

```
ConventionRegistry.Register("IgnoreIfDefault",
            new ConventionPack { new IgnoreIfDefaultConvention(true) },
            t => true);
```

Just add in the constructor of your Repository and everything will work fine. using UpdateOneModel will oblige you to set all fields... In my project, I have Dozen of fields and it is not easy to set all of them. Now I can use ReplaceOneModel with BulkWrite and alone.

```
var client = new MongoClient(settings.Value.ConnectionString);

var database = client.GetDatabase(settings.Value.DatabaseName);

// Add this to the constructor of your Repository and everything will work fine 

ConventionRegistry.Register("IgnoreIfDefault",
            new ConventionPack { new IgnoreIfDefaultConvention(true) },
            t => true);
```

Happy Coding  :-)

Comment: I tried using this solution with no luck.  Still null Id.  Same goes for the [BsonIgnoreIfDefault] attribute.  Its like I'm forced to set each field manually.  What  a pain.  And bug prone whenever a new field gets added to the model.